# Using a variable outside foreach with if statement?

Tags: php, foreach

This code should explain it all..

```
foreach($this->sections as $k => $section){ 

    $preview = array();

    foreach ($section['fields'] as $k => $type) {                               
       $preview[] = $type['type'];
    }

    if ($preview == 'header_preview'){
        echo $preview;
        // I will loop content here based on the $section loop NOT the $type loop
    }

}
```

I just need to get each `$section['fields']` then outside that loop, which again gets a list of all the `$section['fields']` then use one of those field types to create an if statement. The above is non working, I will show you working code here.

```
foreach($this->sections as $k => $section){ 

    foreach ($section['fields'] as $k => $type) {                               
        if ($type['type'] == 'header_preview'){
           //I work but im in a nested loop I need out
        }
     }

  //The main loop here.. the above loop is just to setup data to use inside this loop? Make sense? I hope!

}
```

I hope this makes sense...

Snippet of var_dump `$this->sections`

```
array(26) { ["general"]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(7) "General" ["icon"]=>    string(106) "img/icons/sub.png" ["fields"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=>    string(10) "responsive" ["type"]=> string(6) "switch" ["title"]=> string(35) "Responsive" ["desc"]=> string(10) "Responsive" ["options"]=> array(2) { [1]=> string(2) "On"    [0]=> string(3) "Off" }
```

Comment: your first code is definitely wrong but can you explain please what are you trying to do?

Comment: well I am looping each `$section` there are field types and I am trying to exclude a field type but the only way to access the types is with a foreach loop

Comment: can you add `var_dump($this->sections)` before your parent loop and show us the result and give us an example of the output you need the loop to set in the var `$preview`

Comment: Yeah, but that returns a lot of data, I think it would be better to show you the $section['fields'] dump or is it essential you know the $this->sections?

Comment: i don't need the full list of data inside `$this->sections` i just need to see the structure of this array and to know what you are trying to do and why you need this variable outside the child loop

Comment: I added a snippet.. I have created an array but I dont want to show it in the foreach, because I am going to use header_preview elsewhere.. you can see there is the ['type'] array.. I want to loop through all of the sections but not the ['type'] that is header_preview.. make sense?

Comment: there is no `header_preview` element in your array output but i'll answer your question up to what i understood from your description.

Comment: OK thanks for taking the time to fully understand.. but the reason why you didnt see it is because it was a snippet... you see the first array ['general'] is a section.. inside the general there is the title, icon, then fields.. inside the fields is all my options including type.. but there is no type "header_preview" inside the general section its inside another section (was a hassle to sort the array so I just posted the first section as a snippet sorry bout that).. just use switch in replace.. imagine the question referring to switch makes no difference either way :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible $k has been duplicated and therefore the loop doesn't know what to do. You can try changing $k to $x, see if it works.

```
foreach($this->sections as $k => $section){ 

    $preview = array();

    foreach ($section['fields'] as $x => $type) {                               
       $preview[] = $type['type'];
    }

    foreach($preview as $elem){
        if ($elem == 'header_preview'){
            echo($elem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$preview` is an array, you can NOT echo an array, if don't know what you r typing then please don't give wrong answers!!!

Comment: Well that was his code. I didn't type, The first thing I noticed was $k being used twice.

Comment: Yes dear but you can't correct just one point and leave others this will cause an issue and it will output an error!, better to understand what he is willing to do with his code then answer the question ;)

Comment: It's hard to articulate what I am doing super clearly, but dont over think it, im just trying to access an array that has a list of field types so I can use that to prevent a field type from being in the loop.. My terminology may be off, and I think my logic is obvious but the wording may be off..

Comment: This works William Yang good write up but this contradicts my point, I dont want the if statement in a nested foreach, because in the live code that will mess up my loop... The loop is essential to loop through each section, but I want to limit a section that has the type, header_preview.. maybe I need to reconstruct some logic.. me brain hurts lol

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Maybe

```
foreach($this->sections as $k => $section){ 

    $preview = array();

    foreach ($section['fields'] as $x => $type) {                               
       $preview[] = $type['type'];
    }

    if(!in_array('header_preview', $preview)){

        // Here $preview DOES NOT contain 'header_preview'
        // Do stuff

    } 
}
```

Comment: Testing... Im going to need to add a not ! though.. because I am trying to exclude header_preview..

Comment: Ahh.. then just add ! in front of in_array

Comment: Yeah, nice looking good so far.. need to adjust some stuff.. post back here in a min.. thanks for the effort

Comment: William based on what I gave you helped out very well, nothing more you could have done.. I commented on MaveRicks answer and failed to mention I was using do_settings_sections inside my loop and that handled the loop, its a weird function to me, the above code would have worked had it not been the wordpress function do_settings_sections...

Answer (score 1):

```
$header_preview=false;
foreach($this->sections as $k => $section){ 
    $header_preview=false;// reset the var $header_preview
    foreach ($section['fields'] as $k => $type) {                               
        if ($type['type'] == 'header_preview') $header_preview = true;
    }
    if($header_preview==true){
        //here you can add or extract from this array that has `header_preview` value for one of it's field type
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you for your effort... I failed to mention I was using WordPress's `do_settings_sections` inside the loop, new to that hook/function, but I figured it out I played with it earlier but couldn't figure out the array I was reading, and couldn't access header_preview, but then I did another attempt and got it... Hope I didn't waste your time, I spent about 2 and a half hours too long trying to figure this thing out so I definitely wasted my time... I think by your code failing I realized something was wrong.. insanity defined by Albert Einstein is was I was doing lol.